# Where does nom's "$i" macro argument come from?

Tags: macros, rust, nom

I'm trying to understand how Rust macro captures work and am looking at the [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom) parser library.

Location [nom/src/bytes.rs](https://github.com/Geal/nom/blob/2a09d8f887b6261aed57f70ceb3496c602db65b2/src/bytes.rs#L20) declares macro `tag!` which captures with `($i:expr, $tag: expr)`. 
However throughout the places where `tag!` is used it is used with only one argument, i.e. `tag!("+")`. 
Example: [nom-lua52/op.rs](https://github.com/doomrobo/nom-lua53/blob/2070bf4a0579f6d1201dae34af528c3723e5bb69/src/op.rs#L23). I've read [tutorials](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/) about macros however this construct seems to be special.

It seems like the input `$i` is somehow *implicit*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is that the `tag!()` macro call is inside the `value!` macro, which will match against `tag!` and pass it an additional parameter.  This is described in the file [implementing `tag!`](https://github.com/Geal/nom/blob/master/src/macros.rs#L27).